# Adding elements to a list in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Suppose I have a list in groovy code as:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
```

Now when I use the below code, it changes the list:

```
println(l<<5)
```

Now our list is [1,2,3,4,5]

But when I am using this code:

```
println(l+[6])
```

Nothing happens to the list (except it prints with a 6 at the end.)
But the list is same as [1,2,3,4,5]

What's going on in here? Help please.
Thanks

Comment: `<<` appends an item to a list (modifies the original list) while `+` creates a new list from the two lists (without modifying either of the original ones)

Comment: To add to @UnholySheep's explanation, the GroovyDoc for List's `<<` (leftShift) is: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object) and `+` (plus) is: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#plus(java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: @UnholySheep So How will I know which method modifies the list and which all doesn't? Do I need to keep on checking documentation time and again before using the method?

Comment: @saurav how would you know for any other method (of any class) whether it modifies an object or not? You always need to check the documentation (or source code) unless you know it by heart

Answer (score 2):

`println(l<<5)` is appending `5` to `l` and then printing `l`.

`println(l+[6])` is creating a list that has all of the contents of `l` plus all of the contents on in the list that is on the right hand side of the `+` (in your case it just contains the number `6`).  Then that list is printed.  That does not change the value or state of `l`.